# Is there a way to avoid twisting when applying array and curve modifiers in Blender

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I am pretty new to 3d modelling in general and blender and I am trying to model a road's path. I have a 5m section of road profile (not simply a flat plane, but a road bed and then sloping verges which is vital as the roads need to join seamlessly with premade junctions with this profile), and then apply an array modifier to it to fit to curve and select the curve that describes the road's path. I then apply a curve modifier to it, again selecting the curve. On relatively straight roads this renders an acceptable result, however when the road contains a sizeable bend, the entire road takes on a twist effect leading to a camber which is absolutely not what I want.

Is there a way to combat this twist being applied? I've experimented with importing the terrain I'm trying to lay this road onto, and shrinkwrapping it but that then loses the cross section profile I'm looking for. I had thought I could maybe select all the vertices on the high side, and move them in the Z axis to flatten the road but that doesn't appear to work well at all.

I've experimented with geonodes and while that appears to generate a flat plane for the roadbed, I haven't figured out how I could get the correct cross sectional profile.

Comment: Have you tried "z-up" twist method in properties/object data/shape?

Comment: ... and you can control the camber by Ctrl-T twisting the curve's control-points

Comment: @Nathan Yes, I've got z-up, and I've tried minimum, neither changed the outcome.

Comment: @RobinBetts I tinkered with that, but the sheer number of control points requiring tweaking was just unrealistic. If it could be interpolated from the relative heights of the outside vertices nearest the control point using python, maybe it could be automated. Something to think about I guess.

Comment: Maybe share a representative chunk of your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ Seems odd to need that many control-points on a road, which is by nature smooth, for driving..?